# What benefit is there to use --grep-reflog?

Tags: git, git-reflog

I noticed in the documentation you can specify the parameter `--grep-reflog`

> **--grep-reflog=<pattern>**
>
> > Limit the commits output to ones with reflog entries that match the specified pattern (regular expression). With more than one --grep-reflog, commits whose reflog message matches any of the given patterns are chosen. It is an error to use this option unless --walk-reflogs is in use.

I kind of wanted clarification on how this is different from `--grep`. What benefit is there for looking through actions made through the `git reflog`s? Is it just so you know what is available in `git reflog` so if you wanted to access it, you can?

Comment: where can you supply this option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`--grep` only search applies to commits reachable from a branch head. You would use `--grep-reflog` to search instead commits that are accessible from a reflog entry, which might not otherwise be accessible from an existing branch. I think this is useful primarily for error recovery (finding a commit that is otherwise lost so that you can recover it).

Comment: I guess my confusion is that specifying the `--walk-reflogs` parameter automatically includes the reflogs and you can use `--grep` along with that. Also it seems you can't use `--grep-reflog` unless you specify `--walk-reflogs`. Is there a specific benefit to using that as opposed to just `--grep`?

Comment: Hm. I suspect the benefit is to limit the output to a manageable number of commits (my test with `--grep-reflog` showed only a single commit, even though there were numerous reachable commits found by `--grep` alone). This is probably not the best (or even a correct) answer to your actual question, though.

Comment: I'm gonna accept your answer for now since it seems that's the best we can figure out :P thanks!

Comment: One difference I noticed is that `--grep` doesn't seem to work with `reflog` only `--grep-reflog`.